# Comparing elements of two lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so I need to compare the elements of 2 lists in python,and if they have more than 15 elements in common,it should show a message.I tried to traverse those lists using the for loop,and compare every element from that list,and if they were equal,I made a counter to count my correct answers and if they were above 15 show the message "You passed".But it doesn't work at all,it always says that I passed no matter what
Here is the code:

```
for j in answerList:
    for k in answers:
        if(k==j):
            nr+=1
if(nr>15):
    print("You passed")
else:
    print("You failed")
```

Comment: `'you passed' if len(set(answerList).intersection(set(answers))) >= 15 else 'you failed'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because for `answerList`, the `answer` is re-iterated, so you should use `zip()`

```
for j,k in zip(answerList,answers):
    if(k==j):
        nr+=1
if(nr>15):
    print("You passed")
else:
    print("You failed")
```

Or
`nr=sum(k==j for j,k in zip(answerList,answers))`

Answer (score 0):

By considering `len(answers) == len(answerList)`, you can `zip()` two lists and perform comparison in one line

```
n = len([*filter(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(answerList, answers))])

if n > 15:
     print("You passed")
else:
     print("You failed")
```

FYI: In your case, the time complexity is `O(len^2)` and in this case, it would be `O(n)`